# Python read specific lines of text between two strings

Tags: python, text, readlines

I am having trouble getting python to read specific lines. What i'm working on is something like this:

```
lines of data not needed
lines of data not needed
lines of data not needed

--------------------------------------
    ***** REPORT 1 *****
--------------------------------------

[key] lines of interest are here
[key] lines of interest are here
[key] lines of interest are here
[key] lines of interest are here
[key] lines of interest are here      #This can also be the EOF

--------------------------------------    
    ***** REPORT 2 *****
--------------------------------------

lines of data not needed
lines of data not needed
lines of data not needed         #Or this will be the EOF
```

What I've attempted was something such as:

```
flist = open("filename.txt").readlines()

for line in flist:
  if line.startswith("\t**** Report 1"):
    break
for line in flist:
  if line.startswith("\t**** Report 2"):
    break
  if line.startswith("[key]"):
    #do stuff with data
```

However, I have a problem when the file ends without a end delimiter... Such as when report #2 is not displayed. What is a better approach?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One slight modification which looks like it should cover your problem:

```
flist = open("filename.txt").readlines()

parsing = False
for line in flist:
    if line.startswith("\t**** Report 1"):
        parsing = True
    elif line.startswith("\t**** Report 2"):
        parsing = False
    if parsing:
        #Do stuff with data
```

If you want to avoid parsing the line "***** Report 1"... itself, simply put the start condition after the `if parsing`, i.e.

```
flist = open("filename.txt").readlines()

parsing = False
for line in flist:

    if line.startswith("\t**** Report 2"):
        parsing = False
    if parsing:
        #Do stuff with data 
    if line.startswith("\t**** Report 1"):
        parsing = True
```

Comment: i like it :) I will give this a try tomorrow

Comment: Or, you could put a `continue` statement after `parsing = True` to not parse the '\*\*\*Report 1\*\*\*\*' line as well.

Comment: @mgilson : While I agree that continuing with the loop is inefficient... why did you suggest `continue` instead of `break`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is possible alternative using the itertools module.
Although here the question requires checking for [key], I'm adding also itertool.islice() to show that it is possible to skip few lines after the *start-reading marker* when the user has some prior information.

```
from itertools import takewhile, islice, dropwhile

with open('filename.txt') as fid:
    for l in takewhile(lambda x: '***** REPORT 2 *****' not in x, islice(dropwhile(lambda x: '***** REPORT 1 *****' not in x, fid), 1, None)):
        if not '[key]' in l:
            continue
        print(l)
```