# Select all lines between two lines in windows with python 2.x

Tags: python, python-2.7, powershell

Here is the data that i am trying to manipulate.

## start of show feature

Feature Name          Instance  State

---

bash-shell            1         disabled

bfd                   1         disabled

bgp                   1         disabled

### end of show feature

I am trying to get data between 2 lines.

Here is a powershell example

```
$from = ($switchinfo | Select-String -pattern "start of show feature" | Select-Object LineNumber).LineNumber
$to   = ($switchinfo | Select-String -pattern "end of show feature" | Select-Object LineNumber).LineNumber -gt $from

$a = $switchinfo | where {$_.readcount -gt $from -and $_.readcount -lt $to}
```

So far I have this for python 2.7.12

```
fromStr = 'start of show feature'

with open(filename) as myFile:
    for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):
        if fromStr in line:
            fromline = num

toString = 'end of show feature'

with open(filename) as myFile:
    for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):
        if toString in line:
            toline = num

f=open(filepath)
lines=f.readlines()
print lines[toline]
```

note: filepath is a variable and it is the full path to the file & the filename itself.

```
print lines[toline]
```

works

```
print lines[fromline]
```

works

```
print lines[fromline..toline]
```

doesnt work, it errors out. I was wondering if i can get some help in this regard.
I have referred this [Reading specific lines only (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081836/reading-specific-lines-only-python)
and
[Python read specific lines of text between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732383/python-read-specific-lines-of-text-between-two-strings) (this might help a but)
but no go.

It would also greatly help if the extracted data/lines are stored into a variable.

Comment: try print lines[fromline:toline+1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `print lines[fromline..toline]`

How about:

```
print lines[fromline:toline]
```

> It would also greatly help if the extracted data/lines are stored into a variable. doesnt work, it errors out.

How did you try that? Which error did you get?

Comment: print lines[fromline:toline] 
kinda works but the output is like this

           1         enabled \n', '\n', 'vrrp                  1         disabled\n'
, '\n', 'vrrpv3                1         disabled\n', '\n', 'vtp                
   1         disabled\n', '\n', '\n', ' end of show feature     


I guess I now need to figure out how to format the output properly. The lines are not one below the other but next to each other now.

Comment: @GajendraDAmbi use `for` loop to pint line by line

Comment: `fromStr = 'start of show feature'

with open(filename) as myFile:
    for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):
        if fromStr in line:
            fromline = num
            
toString = 'end of show feature'

with open(filename) as myFile:
    for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):
        if toString in line:
            toline = num
         
store =  lines[fromline:toline+1] 
cutstore = '\n'.join(store)
print cutstore`

Thank you @skycc @drjohn. The above code works now.

Answer (score 1):

```
filename = "somepath/somefilename.txt"
f=open(filename )
lines=f.readlines()

fromStr = 'start of show feature'

with open(filename) as myFile:
    for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):
        if fromStr in line:
            fromline = num

toString = 'end of show feature'

with open(filename) as myFile:
    for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):
        if toString in line:
            toline = num

store =  lines[fromline:toline+1] 
cutstore = '\n'.join(store)
print cutstore
```

Thanks to skycc & drjohn, i was able to arrive at this solution.